# Closed and exact differential form with respect to parameters

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

With respect to parameters $a$ and $b$ decide, whether the 1-differential form is closed or exact.If so, find the primitive function $f(xy),\omega=df$

$
\omega = (y- \frac{a}{2}x^{2a-1}\sin(2by))dx + bx^{2a}\sin^2(by)dy=\omega_1dx+\omega_2 dy
$

I dont really know how to get into this. I am really thankful for any hint on how to solve this.

Comment: When in doubt, go back to definitions: What does it mean for a differential form to be closed? exact?

Comment: closed form means that the exterior derivation is zero and exact form is form that is exterior derivation of some other dif. form ... but I dont know how to use this to be honest

Comment: and what is the exterior derivative of $\omega$?

Comment: Where is the form defined? Over $\mathbb{R}^2$? If yes, since the space is simply connected the form is closed if and only if exact, so you can check when $d\omega=0$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo that might be the problem, I am really not sure what is an exterior derivative of $\omega$

Comment: or is the exterior derivative equal to $\frac{\partial \omega_1}{\partial y} =(1-abx^{2a-1}\cos(2by))$ - $ \frac{\partial \omega_2}{\partial x} = (b\sin^2(by)2ax^{2a-1})$  and I want this to be zero.. ?